# Display 3 columns each row without using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, wordpress

This is a wordpress site http://www.jokerleb.com

Each cell has the following code

```css
.post-block-out {
    margin: 0 0 8px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.post-block-out {
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #E3E4E7;
}

div{
      display: block;

  }



post-block {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 15px 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.post-block-out, .searchblock, .paging, .sidebar-block {
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #E3E4E7;
    }
    
    
 .content_res {
     width: auto;
}


.content_left{
  width:30%; 
  float: none;
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="content_res">
<div class="content_left">

<div class="post-block-out ">
 <div class="post-block">
  <div class="post-left">
   <a href="http://www.jokerleb.com/ads/kyosk-2mx2m/" title="Kyosk 2m×2m"><img class="attachment-ad-medium" alt="" title="" src="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/themes/classipress/images/no-thumb-150x150.png"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="post-right full">
 <div class="tags price-wrap">
  <span class="tag-head"><p class="post-price">$1600$</p></span>
 </div>
   <h3><a href="http://www.jokerleb.com/ads/kyosk-2mx2m/">Kyosk 2m×2m</a></h3>
   <div class="clr"></div>
    <p class="post-meta">
  <span class="dashicons-before folder"><a href="http://www.jokerleb.com/ad-category/home-garden/other-home-garden/" rel="tag" class="cp-fixed-color">Other Home &amp; Garden</a></span> <span class="dashicons-before owner"><a href="http://www.jokerleb.com/author/charbel-2/" title="Posts by Charbel" rel="author" class="cp-fixed-color">Charbel</a></span> <span class="dashicons-before clock"><span>August 25, 2017</span></span>
 </p>

   <div class="clr"></div>

   
   <p class="post-desc">Kyosk ma3moul la snack fi haute rekeb fi madfouf PVC ma3 inaraaa</p>

    <p class="stats">23 total views, 0 today</p>

   <div class="clr"></div>

  </div>

  <div class="clr"></div>

 </div><!-- /post-block -->

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

that snippet is affecting every box on the page, they are now aligned in the middle. I want them  to be 3 columns per row.

- No bootstrap or any grid library because it's affecting the theme, i guess maybe because it has a class called container, so when using bootsrap, the container centers everything. If you know a library that doesn't conflict with the existing code I'd use it.
- It's a very old wordpress theme, many of the styles are stored in the database so if I need to add class I might have to do it in jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ucb0bdmj/

Don't worry about it. And you'll see on the website duplicate css code, don't worry about it, I use a plugin to manage css in the development phase, the code I don't want is `display:none`

All I want is 3 columns on each row. I tried to add float the first left and the third right but the problem is that they move only within their container.

Plus I don't know where to place `<div class='row'>`, I was trying to do it with bootstrap just to see if it would work, I didn't spot the correct place to create new row

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/46173/css-grid-library-that-does-not-conflict-with-existing-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is what you expect[image]

Follow this to make it work:

1. Remove width: 30% of class .content_left
2. Add `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;` to block you want to show. (In this case was the div with id="block1"
3. Add width of 33% for each div with class post-block-out

You can try to add some margin or padding to make the gap between divs.

**important:** I guess this is better than use floats if you want to avoid conflicts. And, if you want to make it responsive, just use media queries and add width: 100%; to each div with class post-block-out

Comment: yes im going to try it now just because you don't use float just a min

Comment: I have to accept your answer mainly because some items were missing in the previous answer

Answer (score 2):

You can try this *responsive* solution:

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box}

.content-left {
  position: relative;
  width: 1200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 10px;
}

.content-left > .post-block-out {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}

.content-left > .post-block-out > img {
  display: block;
  width: 460px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.content-left > .post-block-out > .info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  opacity: .75;
}

.content-left > .post-block-out > .info > span {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.content-left > .post-block-out > .info > .title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .content-left {padding: 0 10px}
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .content-left {column-count: 2}
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .content-left {column-count: 1}
}
```

```html
<div class="content-left">
  <div class="post-block-out">
    <img src="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/themes/classipress/images/no-thumb-150x150.png" alt="">
    <div class="info">
      <span class="title">Kyosk 2m x 2m</span><span class="price-tag">$1,600.00</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-block-out">
    <img src="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/809926-250x250.jpeg" alt="">
    <div class="info">
      <span class="title">Apartment For Sale in JBEIL</span><span class="price-tag">$180,000.00</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-block-out">
    <img src="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/118310-250x250.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="info">
      <span class="title">Apartment for sale in Adonis</span><span class="price-tag">$230,000.00</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-block-out">
    <img src="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/655212-250x250.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="info">
      <span class="title">Duplex for sale in Al Ghiye</span><span class="price-tag">$125,000.00</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-block-out">
    <img src="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/584970-250x250.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="info">
      <span class="title">Honda CRV 2012</span><span class="price-tag">$19,999.00</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-block-out">
    <img src="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/628582-250x250.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="info">
      <span class="title">Malinois puppies For Sale</span><span class="price-tag">$900.00</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-block-out">
    <img src="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/565460-250x250.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="info">
      <span class="title">Villa for Sale in Chabtin</span><span class="price-tag">$225,000.00</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-block-out">
    <img src="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/53048-250x250.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="info">
      <span class="title">Shop for Sale in Ain el Roumani</span><span class="price-tag">$140,000.00</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-block-out">
    <img src="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/601563-250x250.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="info">
      <span class="title">Honda CRV</span><span class="price-tag">$ ???</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-block-out">
    <img src="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/484415-250x250.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="info">
      <span class="title">Apartment in dekwaneh For Rent</span><span class="price-tag">$700.00</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-block-out">
    <img src="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/4610-250x250.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="info">
      <span class="title">Nissan Pathfinder</span><span class="price-tag">$5,000.00</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-block-out">
    <img src="http://www.jokerleb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/667783-250x250.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="info">
      <span class="title">Land for sale at Ain Kfaa<br>(عين كفاع)</span><span class="price-tag">$100,000.00</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.content-left {width:100%; }
.post-block-out { float:left; width:33% }
```

Comment: that's it? I slept 4 am yesterday trying to make it work? excuse me for a bit, I'll go kill myself!!!!!!!!!! thank you so much

Comment: It isn't responsive but it is working on my desktop screen. Chrome developer tools make it pretty easy to play around with the css on a live site.